# Disable pointer-event when hovering router button if disabled

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router-dom

Is it possible to turn off pointer-events on disabled Routerbuttons? My state on the Route is set to disabled due to some criterias not fulfilled that early, but it's still possible to point on it and click, even tho its not doing anything than trigger a message. Do I need to add css class on the route? Was hoping I didn't need to do that.

```jsx
<Route
      disabled={saving || ableToWork === false}
      requiresValidation
      key={`${match.url}/receipt`}
      label={formatMessage(GeneralMessages.verify)}
      loc={`${match.url}/receipt`}
      path={`${match.path}receipt`}
      render={() => (
        <Receipt
          {...rest}
          match={match}
          onCancel={this.onCancel}
          onBack={this.handleOnBack}
        />
      )}
    />,
```

Comment: "on disabled Routerbuttons" - what do you mean by that, is your receipt component a button?

Comment: @JamesMorrison No it just referes to a footer with some content that triggers it. The Route is being rendered as a switch with routes in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to use CSS for this.

The Route component doesn't handle this : [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)